# Epsilon Neighborhoods of the Rationals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, rational-numbers

What is meant when someone discusses an epsilon neighborhood of $\mathbb{Q}$?. Naturally the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$, so what is the epsilon neighborhood? More importantly, what does the following series add up to,
$$\sum_{\substack{
   0 \leq x \leq 1, \\
           x\in\mathbb{Q} }}
 \epsilon (x),$$
where $\epsilon(x)$ denotes the length of the interval $( x - \frac{\epsilon}{2}, x + \frac{\epsilon}{2})$.

Comment: What does $\epsilon(x)$ mean in that sum?

Comment: Chances are that for each $x\in\mathbb Q$, $\epsilon(x)$ is a small number so that the sum of all of them (countably many) is not very large. If that’s the case, I or someone else can explain in an answer what’s probably intended.

Comment: @AdamSaltz My professor defined $\epsilon (x)$ as the interval $(x - \frac{\epsilon}{2}, x + \frac{\epsilon}{2})$ for each $x \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Ok.  What do you mean by $\sum$?  For example what is $(0, 1/2) + (1/4, 3/4)$?  Do you mean union, $\bigcup$?

Comment: @AdamSaltz See this was part of the confusion, he wasn't specific if he meant the sum of the lengths of the intervals, or the union

Comment: So, maybe you should ask him what he meant?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why not discuss both?

Comment: Sorry, why not discuss both *what*? I'm just saying, if your teacher said something, and you don't understand it, it's his job to clarify it for you. That's what he's paid to do. Go ask him what he meant.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'd gladly do that but this assignment is due tomorrow evening. This problem was written hastily at the end of class on wednesday

Comment: (I edited the TeX. Not what you wanted precisely, but this makes the meaning of the series unambiguous, which I suppose is what matters.)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to interpret your question.

If it is interpreted as a sum then (if $\epsilon$ is only allowed to be rational and positive - this is needed for the normal method of infinite series which concerns itself with countable sets), then it diverges. This can be seen easily. Take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and consider some list of rational epsilon with $\epsilon\in (1/2,1)$. There are a countably infinite number of these $\epsilon$ and so the sum of them all, since they're all greater than $1/2$, is also infinite. Since the series is a positive one, this shows that the whole series of all $x$ and $\epsilon$ considerable diverges.

If it's interpreted as a union of all $N_\epsilon (x)$ where $x\in [0,1]$, $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, and $N_\epsilon (x)\subset [0,1]$, it equals $(0,1)$.* This is because the infinite union of open sets is also open. Therefore the union is open. So if $0$ were an element of the union, you would also include elements less than $0$, but we already supposed *no* interval/neighborhood contains elements less than zero. (same with $1$). "The contradiction establishes the theorem." ^^

---

*($N_\epsilon(x)$ is "the neighborhood radius epsilon around x". Note that it varies by a factor of 2 from your original post, but that the definitions leave the problem essentially the same. I'm just treating $\epsilon$ as a radius instead of a diameter of the neighborhood.)

(please comment to let me know if I interpreted your question correctly. The second one is probably what your teacher meant? I find it the most interesting, at least.)